# WCF Rest .NET 4.0 Unhandled Exceptions

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, rest

I've found a bunch of questions that were very close to what I need. But I'm worried that I have missed some important information.

How do I catch all unhandled exceptions using WCF Rest with .NET 4.0?

For security purposes I do not want unhandled exceptions going to the client. I want to log all exceptions and for unknown exceptions just send back 500 Internal Server Error.

My best research so far tells me I need to implement IErrorHandler and throw WebFaultExceptions for known exceptions. One issue I have with this is that all of my business logic is in a separate project from the WCF service and it doesn't make sense to throw a Web exception from the underlying class library since the class library could be consumed by another process which may not be a WCF Rest Service. Is there a nice way to map exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement `IErrorHandler` and use it to map exceptions. You don't need to throw `WebFaultException` from your business logic, just throw your custom exceptions.

For example, you can map `YourCustomException` to some simple json string. Instead of string you can put some object. Sample `IErrorHandler.ProvideFault` implementation:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault) 
{        
        if (error is YourCustomException)
        {
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, string.Empty, String.Format("Error: {0}.", error.Message), new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string)));
            fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json));

            webOperationContextWrapper.SetOutgoingResponseStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
}
```

So when `YourCustomException` is thrown by business logic it will be catched by the handler and converted to proper fault.

See also: [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/ExtendingWCF_PartI.aspx)